# How to customize Json(De)Serializer in Spring Kafka producer/consumer? (self response)

Tags: spring-kafka, jackson-databind

As Spring doc suggests [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/#serdes-mapping-types), you can customize the behaviour of Json(De)Serializer in Kafka with an `ObjectMapper` but it does not specify how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `Json(De)Serializer` has a constructor which takes an `ObjectMapper` as arg, so you can inject the bean like:

```
@Bean 
Deserializer jsonDeserializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new JsonDeserializer(objectMapper);
}
```

as stated [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/680).

Also, if you need to add trusted package, you need to:

- pick an `ObjectMapper` from context, pass it to the bean of json serializer
- in the `@Bean` method, add trusted package
- pass this bean to factory to get the final consumer

And the link above also mentions that if you use context properties to get the `Json(De)Serializer`, it is generated by Kafka, without being aware of any context.

Comment: That is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#json-serde). `>You can perform only simple configuration with properties. For more advanced configuration (such as using a custom ObjectMapper in the serializer and deserializer), you should use the producer and consumer factory constructors that accept a pre-built serializer and deserializer. ...`

Comment: Yes, it says "the factory has a constructor which accepts a serializer", but it has not mentioned "the serializer also has a constructor with ObjectMapper as arg". The last mile is not documented.

Comment: Huh? `>You can perform only simple configuration with properties. For more advanced configuration (such as using a custom ObjectMapper in the serializer and deserializer),` - seems clear enough to me; I mean `such as using a custom ObjectMapper`